# Converting Sql Server 2012 RTM from trial to licensed edition

Tags: sql-server, licensing, evaluation, sql-server-2012

Similar questions have been asked about 2008, but there appears to be a dearth of information on SQL Server 2012.

1. Does it require a reinstall?
2. Will it go through an upgrade process (and what does that entail) or is it just a magic SKU switch?
3. Is the process exactly the same going from any edition of Trial to any licensed edition?

Comment: rtm does not require a reinstall not sure about all the details though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is a SKU Upgrade which is done on the maintenance tab of the installer when you first open it (the first app where you would normally click the "Install a standalone instance..." option.

The process is the same when going from Trial to Standard, BI or Enterprise.

There will be a small outage, so if you are already in production with the server you'll need to schedule a small outage window.